# How to call parametrized constructor of one class in another class in Java

Tags: java, oop

```
class Department{

  int dep_id;
  string dep_name;

Department(string dep_id , string dep_name)
{
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Department ID");
dep_id=input.nextInt();
system.out.println("Enter Department Name");
dep_name=input.nextString();
void Display(){
  System.out.println("Deaprtment ID is : " + dep_id);
  System.out.println("Deaprtment Name is : " + dep_name);
  
}

class Professor extends Person
{         //This person is different class

 string profName;
  Department dept;
 Professor(string profName){
  Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Professor Name");
   profName=input.nextString();


 }
```

Now I have to add
A data field named dept of type Department
A two-argument constructor to initialize both attributes of user-defined values
How can I call Department class in Professor Class

Comment: super(a,b) ???????

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) When asking for help, please indent and format your code reasonably and consistently. (It's a good idea to do that for yourself, too.) Also be sure to resolve basic compilation errors prior to asking (unless, of course, it's the compilation error you're asking about). Java is case-sensitive, `string` != `String`.

Comment: in professor class create a constructor to take inputs for professor class , dept_id and dept_name
then call the constructor of dept class i.e. dept = new Department(dept_id, dept_name);

Comment: Ravi professor class is not subclass hence it's not duplicate of Calling superclass .....

Comment: @RajivKapoor his code was totally messed. So, I didn't read complete question instead just read the question title

Answer (score 1):

Hope this makes it clear

```
    class Professor extends Person { // This person is different class

    string profName;
    Department dept;

    Professor(string profName, int dept_id, String dept_name) {
        this.profName = profName;
        dept = new Department(dept_id, dept_name);
    }
}
```

use scanner in your main class to get these inputs